# How to accept only defined URLs in a NodeJS express API

Tags: node.js, express

F.E.: My NodeJS script runs on a server with and can handle stuff like:

```
app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
    res.json([{ name: "Brian" }]);
});
```

For an API-scenario, I would like to have that only specific websites can place an GET/POST or whatever to the NodeJS API server, **before** any authentication happens. Is that possible?

Comment: Do you mean only accept requests from particular domains? How do you intend to check that, Origin header?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you could achieve this using Cross-Origin Resource Sharing. Although this will only work for browsers, people would still be able to get this data by using CURL or other similar tools.

```
var cors = require('cors')
```

and

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://example.com'
}))
```

or

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: ['http://example1.com', 'http://example2.com']
}))
```

If you want to read more about it you can check here: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Hi Matthew, thank you, this is very interesting. So basically, when I POST to my API with PHPcurl and respond that

Answer (score 3):

A few hints for you

1. You could create your own middleware to do anything you want:

   Let say I have a middleware:

   ```
   const checkdomain = (req, res, next) => {
       //Check domain here
       // ...
       next();
   }
   ```

   Then you could add this to your router:

   ```
   app.get('/users', checkdomain,  function(req, res){});
   ```
2. A simple way to whitelist 1 domain (i.e. accept only request from that domain, you could use `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, but it's not a recommend way, as you will depend on request header.
   I understand from your question, that you already recognised that you need to build your own authentication check, so this domain check is just a additional helper, you should not totally rely on this.

In your `checkdomain`, you could add:

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://example.com");
```

Another way to check:

```
if( req.headers.host === "https://example.com") { //do stuff }
```

Comment: Say my Nodejs express server sets the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`to only accept request from "https://my-website.com", will cURL or Postman be able to access it?

Comment: Also to clarify, why is setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` not a recommended way, and what does it have to do with it depending on request header? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Jarrett, yes, Postman, cURL, or other method of accessing API should work, but not browser.  Therefore, instead of relying on `CORS`, you should consider on implementing the authentication login (token base for example) to help on security. This is what all open API platform do.

Comment: The authentication token based system that I was thinking of using would be JWT. However, if a certain user were to inspect the network in the browser, they would be able to view the JWT and use it to spam a certain route with request, and the server would have no way of differentiating it with a actually valid request; due to the valid JWT being provided. How would you secure your routes in this case?

Comment: @Jarrett spamming is a different thing. If your app is having that much complicated, you should apply rate limit for your system. Secondly, JWT is securely enough, as the backend server just need to make sure that token is generated by itself, not from other fake server, hence real user

Comment: Just to check too, doesn't `req.headers.host` actually just refer to the address of the host server itself? And would not change?